# need to add a column to my query results output and update that column with conditional values from another column in the same query table

Tags: postgresql

I want to add a new column (see site AS Location) in my query results where the values are based off of what is in the 'site' column.  For example when 'site' = 'test' THEN SET Location = 'test1'.

I keep getting the error that Location does not exist.

I need assistance in adding the column named 'Location' to my query results and not ALTER the actual tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (accessionnumber) 
           id,
           accessionnumber,
           patientname,
           patientid,
           patientdateofbirth,
           patientsex,
           studydescription,
           studydate,
           referringphysician,
           organization,
           peerreviewanalyticsview.comment,
           status,
           reviewedon,
           reviewedby,
           type,
           procedurecode,
           modalities,
           reportingradiologist,
           site,
           site AS Location,
           peerreviewid
FROM   workflowquality.peerreviewanalyticsview
       LEFT OUTER JOIN workflowquality.peerreviewscore
                    ON workflowquality.peerreviewanalyticsview.id =
                       workflowquality.peerreviewscore.peerreviewid
```

Comment: Adding sample before and after data would really help your question.

Comment: Remove the comma before the `FROM`. Use the `CASE...WHEN ` for your conditional column.

Comment: I added  CASE WHEN site = 'inv' THEN Location = 'sj'  END.  I receive an error saying Location does not exist.

Comment: CASE WHEN site = 'inv' THEN 'sj' END location

Comment: I still get a Location does not exist.  I must not be stating it correctly in my select statement.  I am adding a new column called Location like this:  site, site AS Location.

Comment: Edit your question to add your latest query statement..so that I can correct it

Comment: Got it.  Thanks Anand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `CASE...WHEN` statement in your select query, like below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (accessionnumber) Id, accessionnumber, column2,....
site, CASE WHEN site ='test' THEN 'test1' 
         END Location, peerreviewid FROM table1...<join clause>
```

You can add multiple WHEN segments, and also there is an `ELSE` part if none of the conditions match.